# How to securely integrate Facebook Messenger bot with existing nodejs backend?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sails.js, messenger

I currently have a working NodeJs backend (build with Sailsjs), that hosts rest services for a mobile app I'm building.

Now I would like to expand to Facebook Messenger so I can give my users the option to communicate with a bot instead of using the app.

For example if a user wants to lookup his next appointment he can open the app and look it up, or open Messenger and ask "when is my next appointment?".
In order to get this working I have to recognize the Messenger user as an existing user in my database. To do this I'm currently using Facebook Messenger [account linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking). I managed to get the account linking working and save the user PSID to my database.
For the bot I'm currently using [Motion.ai](https://www.motion.ai/) (thinking of using an other service). All the messages are passed to My Motion bot webhook and my backend webhook. It doesn't feel right to use two webhooks for one app, or is it ?

The rest services for my mobile app are all using a webtoken to recognize the user making the call, but my Messenger bot users don't have a webtoken, how can I solve this, and still have a secured platform ? 
Maybe I can give the user the option to send a token or a PSID and the Motion.ai token? The Motion.ai token will be the same for all users but still somewhat secure my backend because it will only accept reqeusts from the Motion.ai server.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

**Ok, I found a way to get it working**. 
Since I'm building a Dutch bot Motion.ai wasn't working out for me. I switched to Api.ai mainly for their support for the Dutch language, but also because of the advanced language processing capabilities.
I found out that I can't reuse my controllers for my bot and my mobile app. To solve this I moved all the logic to a service (better design), that I can call in my bot controller and rest service controller.

To get everything working in a secured manner I did the following:

**1:** Api.ai does not support the account linking callback made by Facebook so I use my server as the webhook for my Facebook app.

**2:** I use a Sails Policy to acknowledge the Facebook Token, check the UserId in my database (if it does not match send a account_linking request to the user), and handle the account_linking callbacks.
To secure the Api.ai webhook I used an other policy that uses basic auth.

**2.1** if the user has not been linked yet the linking process will send a login form so he can login with his email and password used in my app.

**2.2:** If the user email and password match I send a redirect link to fb to confirm the login. I also add a token containing the usersid (from my database).

**2.3:** Fb will now notify the user that he has successfully loged in and send a account_linking callback with the token they received from me. Since the userid is in the token I can now lookup the user in my database and update his FacebookID with the id I receive from Facebook. Now the user is officially loged in.

**3:** Once the Policy is confirmed I use a controller to redirect the Facebook message to Api.ai.

**4:** Finally Api.ai will send back a response to my server that will handle it and redirect a message to the fb user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can switch to an another service for you bot as you said, switch to [api.ai](http://api.ai/).

Because it offers a [**one-click** Facebook Messenger integration](https://docs.api.ai/docs/facebook-integration) and it seems to be leading the bot market.

There is also [wit.ai](https://wit.ai/) but I didn't have tested it yet.

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you, but I knew about api.ai and wit.ai. They will indeed simplify the bod building process , but still wont solve my security issue...